# Accessing internet hosts from qemu guests behind a bridged network

Tags: iptables, opensuse, qemu, bridge

I am trying to set up a number of qemu quests on the same private network. I want them to not be accessible outside the host but they should be able to access each other and resources from the internet. For context this is going to be a thrash kubernetes setup.

What I have done:

1. Set up a bridge interface with a private ip

```
ip link add name br0 type bridge
ip addr add 10.24.0.1/24 dev br0
ip link set dev br0 up
```

2. Allowed access for the `qemu-bridge-helper` by adding the following line to `/etc/qemu/bridge.conf`

```
allow br0
```

3. Started a DHCP server bound to the bridge interface

```
dnsmasq --interface=br0 --bind-interfaces --dhcp-range=10.24.0.2,10.24.0.254
```

4. Allowed guest communication to skip iptables

```
sysctl -w net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=0
```

At this point, I can:

- from the host, access (ping/ssh) the guests
- from the guests, access (ping/ssh) other guests
- from the guests, access (ping/ssh) the host
- from the guests, ping the host's other IPs
- from the guests, perform hostname lookups

What I can not do is access anything beyond the host, e.g. internet resources.

I have docker installed and docker networking works, e.g. `docker run -t alpine ping google.com` works perfectly.

It seems to me that I need to allow packets to be forwarded from the `10.24.0.0` network, but I don't know how to do that. I have tried

```
iptables -I FORWARD -i br0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -o br0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o '!br0' --source 10.24.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

but that does not help.

And to clear up things, IP forwarding is enabled:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

What can I change to allow internet access from my QEMU guests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you correct the incorrect rule:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o '!br0' --source 10.24.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
                               ^^^^^^^^^
```

(which will never match because there is no interface named `!br0`)

into:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING ! -o br0 --source 10.24.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

Simple test to show iptables doesn't consider `'!br0'` as a negation, using (easier) a dummy interface:

```
ip link add '!test' type dummy
ip address add dev '!test' 10.11.12.1/24
ip link set '!test' up
iptables -I OUTPUT -o '!test'
```

Now you can try pinging through this interface: `ping 10.11.12.2` and will see with for example with `iptables-save -c |grep test` that the counter increases when the interface is used, and doesn't if not.

```
# iptables-save -c|grep test
[1:84] -A OUTPUT -o !test
```

Comment: Ok I'll believe you.